# Sharing configuration between Azure services

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-web-app-service, azure-worker-roles

How can configuration in Azure be shared between an Azure Worker Role and an Azure Web Service?

Answer (score 2):

Cannot be shared directly - there is no magic wand or out-of-the-box-system-valid-for-all-possible-programming-languages-supported-on-azure. 
You can, however write your own [custom configuration section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) and store / retrieve data from a common configuration store (such as [Azure Table Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/tables/) to store key value pairs or a [Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/) to store XML configuration section directly)

This approach is rather simple, effective and should not cost you enormous efforts.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be the management of these configuration settings through Powershell. The connection strings and app settings for the Web App, once contained within the Azure portal, can be both updated and retrieved via [Azure Powershell cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554330.aspx#Anchor_1). These same retrieved configuration settings can then be used to update the configuration for the Worker Role.

This way all configuration can be managed with one script.

Comment: Also viable solution, but when you keep your `single source of truth` then?

Answer (score 0):

Store them in a Key Vault. Cache the configuration values, it seems Key Vault is currently (end of 2017) only able to manage around 250 connections per second.

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/